# JQuery each function how to force consecutive operation

Tags: jquery, function, each

Using JQuery .each function() yet it is operating on all elements at the same time. Instead I want it to be sequential. So operating on one function once complete the second etc.. etc..

```
  $('#fader').children().hide();

$('#fader').children().each(function(){

        $(this).fadeIn(2000,function(){
            $(this).delay(4000);
            $(this).fadeOut(2000);
        });     
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a recursive function like this:

```
function fader(elm) {
  elm.fadeIn(2000, function(){
    elm.delay(4000);
    elm.fadeOut(2000, function() {
      if (elm.next()) {
        fader(elm.next());
      }
    });
  });
}

$('#fader').children().hide();

fader($('#fader').children(':first'));
```

Comment: brilliant. How to make it loop once its completed

Comment: setInterval(function() { fader($('#fader').children(':first')); }, 1000); - this will loop over and over with 1 second pause;

Comment: Instead of my original last line. Note that this will start the whole fading with 1 second delay. If you want to start it instantly, keep both lines.